# replace whole string when certain word occurs in sentence javascript/Google Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a Google Chrome extension where every sentence on a webpage where the word trump is inside to be invisible. Replacing just the word trump with an empty space works, but I can't figure out how to delete the rest of a sentence.

Here is my code:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('*');

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var element = elements[i];

    for (var j = 0; j < element.childNodes.length; j++) {
        var node = element.childNodes[j];

        if (node.nodeType === 3) {
            var text = node.nodeValue;
            var replacedText = text.replace(/trump/gi, '');

            if (replacedText !== text) {
                element.replaceChild(document.createTextNode(replacedText), node);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problems to solve:

1. Find the position of the keyword (trump) in the text
2. Determine what a sentence is
3. Remove the sentence that contains the keyword

We can do the first one with JavaScript String indexOf() Method that will return the position of the keyword in the text.

The second one is going to be hard (depending on how well you want it to work). Determining what a sentence is hard problem for computers, that is why your phone will capitalize anything after a '.' for example. You could start by experimenting with splitting your text along the sentence ending characters (.!?).

The third one is not so hard once you have the second pinned down. Take the characters before the keyword (with the JavaScript String substring() Method for example) and use splits, same with the text after the keyword.